# mongoimport ignore field value 0

Tags: mongodb, csv, field, mongoimport

I have a lot of data in CSV with a lot of fields for which the value is 0.

I would like to import all that data into a collection, but ignore the fields when the value is 0 (not ignore the row, just the fied).

Without ignore the 0 fields, my command is :
`mongoimport --db merch --collection output --type csv --headerline --file export_hub_dev.csv`

Is there any option with mongoimport which permits to do that ? For example something like `--parseGrace skipField` but with the 0 value ?

Or any other way to do that easily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first import the csv and then remove the fields by [$UNSET](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/). You need to run this for each fields one by one.
The update format is

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>
   }
)
```

Comment: $unset update only the first document matched... If i'm doing a loop on my 14 millions lines, it will run for hours. Do you have any other solution ?
Or a solution with $unset, maybe i'm wrong about that ?

Comment: @Toma, You can specify multi property true, when you update.